# Assembly plugin can't copy Java runtime image

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm using assembly plugin to aggregate JRT (Java runtime image) and some app resources into end user distribution. The usage us pretty simple:

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>assembly-win64</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>dist/win64</outputDirectory>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/windows.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**windows.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">

    <id>windows</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <fileSets>
        ... more resources
        <fileSet>
            <directory>target/runtime-images/win64</directory>
            <outputDirectory>app</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>

</assembly>
```

All paths are 100% correct. However, if `target/runtime-images/win64` contains actual JRT image, assembly plugin just ignores it. Here how it looks in debug:

```
[DEBUG] FileSet[app/] dir perms: -1 file perms: -1
[DEBUG] The archive base directory is 'null'
```

No copy attempts, no errors, nothing. How do I know that path is correct? Because if I put some trash files into the same directory (instead of JRT image) everything works like a charm.

I use Windows, so it seems no specific file permissions magic required.

Is anyone else ever faced the same issue? Or are there any Maven alternatives to assembly plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I've found the problem. It's not so obvious so I post it here, maybe it helps someone once.

I've declared all plugins in parent pom. No configuration, just versions, so I don't have to specify plugin version in each child module.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.assembly.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.moditect</groupId>
            <artifactId>moditect-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.moditect.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then in the child module I've used these plugins in order they have to be executed.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
            ... configuration
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.moditect</groupId>
            <artifactId>moditect-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
            ... configuration
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But Maven inherits plugin order from parent pom.
I've never expected this thing can be so stupid.